# PHP Store checkbox state with pagination

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, pagination

I have a view with a couple houndred results. The results are displayed with a pagination systeem. Every page have ten results. Every row has an checkbox and the value of this boxes are userID's. Now when you check some boxes on page 1 and you go to page 2 and back they are gone.

I'm working with Laravel 5.1.

I know this could be solved to store them in a session.
I already have that the value of page 1 is stored into the session.
But when you go to page 2 and select some boxes the value from page 1 boxes are gone.

I'm using jquery ajax to post the array with the checked checkbox values to PHP.

```
                    // Send checked userID with jquery ajax
                    $(document).on('click', '.checkboxstudentClass', function()
                    {
                        var students = $("input[name='student[]']:checked").map(function()
                        {
                            return this.value;
                        }).get();

                        // Ajax
                        $.ajax
                        ({
                            type: "POST",
                            dataType : 'json',
                            async: false,
                            url: 'pos/selectStudentToJson',
                            data: { studentID: students },
                            headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN' : '{{ csrf_token() }}' },
                            success: function () {// dosomething },
                            failure: function() {// dosomething}
                        });
```

The html looks like

```
<input type="checkbox" name="student[]" class="checkboxstudentClass" value="3">
<input type="checkbox" name="student[]" class="checkboxstudentClass" value="6">
<input type="checkbox" name="student[]" class="checkboxstudentClass" value="7">
<input type="checkbox" name="student[]" class="checkboxstudentClass" value="8">
<input type="checkbox" name="student[]" class="checkboxstudentClass" value="9">
```

This is how my function in PHP look like

```
public function selectStudentToJson(Request $request)
{
    $_SESSION['checked'][] = $request->get('studentID');
}
```

When i check some boxes on the first page and print the session this is my result

```
Array
(
    [checked] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 3
                    [1] => 4
                    [2] => 5
                )

        )

)
```

When i go to page 2 and select some boxes the value from page 1 is gone
for example

```
Array
(
    [checked] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 17
                    [1] => 18
                    [2] => 19
                )

        )

)
```

How could i store the selected values from all pages

Comment: if you can implement datatables then check this link https://editor.datatables.net/examples/api/checkbox.html

Comment: This could be a last solution. But the problem is that the session value from page 1 is gone when i select boxes on page 2